# Animate Android Action Bar Menu Item appearance

Tags: android, animation, material-design, user-experience

I have an activity in an android app with fragments displayed using a pager.
One of the three fragments shows a menu item (always displayed as action) and an overflow menu, the two others fragments show in the app bar only the first menu item (but not the overflow menu).
My problem is that when I switch from one tab to another, the menu is not updating smoothly.
Is it possible to add animations to menu inflation ?
Has anyone ever encountered such an issue and how did you handle it ?

Here is the app bar :
[image: First state with two icons]
[image: Second state with only one icon]

And here is how I inflate the menu inside the fragment, of course, the other fragment is inflating another XML file.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
}
```

Please feel free to ask for more details ;-)

Thanks for helping !

Comment: plz check my answer

Answer (score 0):

In you fragment please write this line in your oncreateview mehod:

```
  setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

and implement this mehod:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_referesh, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.refresh:
            pageNumber=1;
            getWebServiceData1();
            return false;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: I don't get what your answer is supposed to change to my problem. The methods you are asking me to implement are 1) already implemented and 2) not animating the menu items, are they ?

Comment: @Arthur then just add setHasOptionsMenu(true); in your OnCreateView method

Comment: the menu is correctly displayed and the onCreateView method already contains this line. The issue is about animating smoothly menu entries when they appear and especially the overflow menu as it moves the other item on the left to make room for it.